# HtmlUnit send parameters to javascript file

Tags: javascript, java, htmlunit

I used the following code for a post request with htmlunit

```
final WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
WebRequest requestSettings = new WebRequest(new URL("www.URLHERE.com"), HttpMethod.POST);

requestSettings.setRequestParameters(new ArrayList());
requestSettings.getRequestParameters().add(new NameValuePair("fruit", "orange"));
HtmlPage page = webClient.getPage(requestSettings);
```

Now, in that page how can I get the name-value parameters through javascript?
That is, I want to access fruit=orange in that html page.
Since it is a headless browser, "window" object would not be available.

Is there any other way I can get the information sent through htmlunit in the page throught javascript?

Comment: I cannot understand what do you want, please be more explicit. Thank you!

Comment: @beniaminp I want to access that name value pair sent from htmlunit in the html page script tags